# How do you stop CocoaPods from linking against a dependency for a framework?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

Say I've developed a framework which contains a binary which uses `OCMock` with all the dependencies that I need. Now when I create a `Podspec` for it and try to use it, I find that I need to have `OCMock` added a dependency.

Say I have the following in my Podfile -

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target "MyAppTests" do
  inherit! :search_paths
  pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.0.1'
end
```

However, the OCMock binary code is already present in my framework bundle, so this causes double inclusion errors. Is there any way in `CocoaPods` that I can prevent OCMock from being added in the `Link Binary With Libraries` Build Phase of my Pods project, basically preventing it from being linked directly?

Comment: Can you add all of your podfile please - you've probably got OCMock specified somewhere else as well?

Comment: Wait, hang on, just reread your question! Why do you have the OCMock binaries in your app already, why not just use the cocoapods version?

Comment: Yes I do. Packaged as a prebuilt lib.

Comment: Why not just use cocoapods to manage it; or why bother including it in your podfile at all. Why use both methods at the same time?

Comment: @deanWombourne probably to optimize build speed